# The command "backup:run" does not exist. while executing command using controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-controller, laravel-backup

I'm trying to back up the system using an HTTP request(using a button). I've configured my codebase according to the  [laravel spatie](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-backup/v7/installation-and-setup) documentation. When I tried to run the command `php artisan backup:run` in the terminal it executes just fine and gives a backup file(.zip)

But when I tried to run the command using a controller it gives,

```
Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException
The command "backup:run" does not exist.
```

Here's my controller,

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

class BackupController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $artisan = \Artisan::call('backup:run');
        $output = \Artisan::output();
        ...
    }
}
```

and here's my route,

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])
    ->get('/backup', [BackupController::class, 'index'])
    ->name('backup');
```

I've tried to solve the problem by adding `Spatie\Backup\BackupServiceProvider::class,` to `app.php`, clearing cache and also tried to redo the whole process from the beginning. But unfortunately, the same error appears.

Hoping for some help to solve the issue, thanks in advance.